# How it's using vert.x

Tags: vert.x, quarkus

A question is running into my mind for a several days ago.

I read several docs about `vert.x` and `quarkus`.

1. Which kind of message are sent throuh event-bus? Only received http request?
2. Has it sense to configure an clustered eventbus inside a quarkus application? Any example?

Those above question have not been able to find some lights.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can send any type of message through the Vert.x Event Bus, as long as a codec exists for this particular type. There are several built-in codecs, but you can register custom codecs too.

Quarkus does not support clustering officially so far. You can [make it work](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10889) with some tweaks, though.

From my perspective (I'm a Vert.x development team member), it can be useful to have a clustered eventbus inside Quarkus, just as it can be useful inside a Vert.x application. There are plenty of articles on the web about use cases.